# Preview shows nothing - Camera X API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I'm trying to implement a camera interface for the user but the Camera X API does not work for any version.

I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#0) to get started and it uses `1.1.0-beta01`.

This launches the application but shows no preview, same with all the other stable releases - `1.2.2`, `1.2.1`, `1.2.0`, or the latest alpha `1.3.0-alpha05`

The code that's starting the preview -

```
private fun startCamera() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)  

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            }

        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
            .build()

        try {
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this as LifecycleOwner,
                cameraSelector,
                preview
            )

        } catch(exc: Exception) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
```

The output log -

```
D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@9b50fe5[id=1]                         OPEN                  
    Camera@5d56162[id=0]                         UNKNOWN               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1)
D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} from OPEN and null
D/CameraStateMachine: Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null}
D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-197d57c7-7404-41af-a14a-c44035704c87242750247] for camera: 1
D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-197d57c7-7404-41af-a14a-c44035704c87242750247] for camera: 1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@9b50fe5[id=1]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENED --> OPENED
D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=StateError{code=4, cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot complete surfaceList within 5000}} from OPEN and StateError{code=4, cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot complete surfaceList within 5000}
D/CameraStateMachine: Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=StateError{code=4, cause=java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot complete surfaceList within 5000}}
E/Camera2CameraImpl: Unable to configure camera 1, timeout!
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

I am running it on a physical device - API level 32

Comment: Can you share the code you're trying to run? Also, have you given camera permissions to your app?

Comment: I'm using the exact same code that's provided in the codelab and yes I have given permission to use the camera on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

In cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
this as LifecycleOwner,
cameraSelector,
preview
)

change 'this as LifecycleOwner' to 'this' .
and if you followed the guide mentioned above and did not change the variable name then in it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
change 'binding' to 'viewBinding'

Hope this helps.